# Como adicionar uma lista de elementos no django?

Tags: html, python, django

Preciso listar elementos que correspondem ao mesmo item do meu banco de dados. Meu banco de dados possui estes elementos:

| Fruta | cor |
| --- | --- |
| Laranja | verde |
| Laranja | laranja |
| Maçã | amarela |
| Maçã | vermelha |
| Kiwi | marrom |

tenho que mostrar no link "/laranja" os seguintes itens: verde, laranja.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

def lista(models.Model):
     fruta = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
     cor = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
```

views.py

```
from .models import lista

class fruta(TemplateView)
    def cor_fruta():
         cor = lista.objects.all()
         response = {'cor':cor}
         return response
    template_name = 'frutas.html'
```

frutas.html

```
<div class="cores">
    listas com as cores da laranja
    {% for value in cor %}
        <p>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ value.cor }}</td>
            </tr>
        </p>
    {% empty %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">Sem registro</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

O erro que está acontecendo é que não aparece nada, nem as cores nem o "Sem registro"

Comment: Cara este código está estranho. Em seu model `lista` não existe o atributo "cor", você apenas declarou fruta duas vezes. Talvez por isso o erro.

Comment: eu que escrevi errado na pergunta, o segundo era pra ser cor, vou consertar aqui, vlw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhando pela documentação do [class-based-view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView) está faltando implementar o método `get_context_data`.

Segue um exemplo de implementação baseado em seu código:

***views.py***

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from .models import lista

class fruta(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'frutas.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cor'] = lista.objects.all()
        return context
```